# Hide/Collapse div when only scrolling vertically

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, hide

I'm developing a hamburger menu for the mobile version of my site. You can see exactly how it works on this codepen: 
http://codepen.io/terrorsaurusrex/pen/gluFh

As you can see, you click the hamburger menu and the div with links expands downwards. If you scroll, the div collapses and the menu returns to it's initial state. This is the script telling the div to collapse if the window is scrolled:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) //AUTOMATICALLY HIDES THE NAV WHEN SCROLLING STARTS
{
  if($("#"+slideNavName).attr('class')=="revealed") //SEE IF YOUR NAV IS OPEN
  {
    //CHANGE ICON BACK INTO A HAMBURGER
    $("#"+rectangleName+"1").toggleClass(showRect+" "+topRectX);
    $("#"+rectangleName+"2").toggleClass(showRect+" "+hideRectX);
    $("#"+rectangleName+"3").toggleClass(showRect+" "+bottomRectX);

    //HIDE YOUR NAVIGATION
    $("#"+slideNavName).toggleClass('revealed hidden');
  }
});
```

I wish to put a horizontally scrollable div within the div that appears when pressing the hamburger button. Is there a way to rewrite this script so that the hamburger div only collapses when the window is scrolled vertically only, and remains when scrolled horizontally?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNEXaJ)

**Description**

Simply detecting if the scroll is horizontal or vertical if it is horizontal ignore the scroll tasks.

**JS**

```
//THIS WAS MADE WITH LOTS OF VARIABLES, SO YOU CAN NAME THINGS HOWEVER YOU LIKE
//IF YOU UNDERSTAND JS AND JQUERY, YOU SHOULD BE ABLE TO PICK THIS APART HOW YOU SEE FIT

var hamburger = "hamb"; //THIS IS THE NAME OF YOUR HAMBURGER BUTTON

var slideNavName = "slideDown"; //THIS IS THE NAME OF YOUR HIDING NAVIGATION

var rectangleName = "rect"; //THIS IS THE NAME OF YOUR LITTLE HAMBURGER RECTANGLES, MINUS THE NUMBERS (SEE CSS COMMENTS)

//YOU MAY CHANGE ALL OF THESE IF YOU NEED TO (SEE CSS COMMENTS)
var showRect = "showRect";
var topRectX = "topRectX";
var hideRectX = "hideRectX";
var bottomRectX = "bottomRectX";
var prevLeftPosition = 0;

$("#" + hamburger).click(function(event) //CHECK IF YOUR BUTTON IS PRESSED
  {
    if ($("#" + slideNavName).attr('class') == "hidden") //CHECKS TO SEE IF YOUR MENU IS CURRENTLY CLOSED
    {
      //CHANGE ICON TO AN 'X'
      $("#" + rectangleName + "1").toggleClass(showRect + " " + topRectX);
      $("#" + rectangleName + "2").toggleClass(showRect + " " + hideRectX);
      $("#" + rectangleName + "3").toggleClass(showRect + " " + bottomRectX);

      //REVEAL YOUR NAVIGATION
      $("#" + slideNavName).toggleClass('hidden revealed');
    } else if ($("#" + slideNavName).attr('class') == "revealed") //CHECKS TO SEE IF YOUR MENU IS CURRENTLY OPEN
    {
      //CHANGE ICON BACK INTO A HAMBURGER
      $("#" + rectangleName + "1").toggleClass(showRect + " " + topRectX);
      $("#" + rectangleName + "2").toggleClass(showRect + " " + hideRectX);
      $("#" + rectangleName + "3").toggleClass(showRect + " " + bottomRectX);

      //HIDE YOUR NAVIGATION
      $("#" + slideNavName).toggleClass('revealed hidden');
    }
  });

//BONUS!!! AN OPENED NAV DISSAPEARS WHEN SCROLLING!!

$(window).scroll(function(event) //AUTOMATICALLY HIDES THE NAV WHEN SCROLLING STARTS
  {
    var horizontalScroll = false;
    var currentLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if (prevLeftPosition != currentLeft) {
      prevLeftPosition = currentLeft;
      horizontalScroll = true;
    }
  console.log(horizontalScroll);
    if ($("#" + slideNavName).attr('class') == "revealed") //SEE IF YOUR NAV IS OPEN
    {
      if (!horizontalScroll) {
        //CHANGE ICON BACK INTO A HAMBURGER
        $("#" + rectangleName + "1").toggleClass(showRect + " " + topRectX);
        $("#" + rectangleName + "2").toggleClass(showRect + " " + hideRectX);
        $("#" + rectangleName + "3").toggleClass(showRect + " " + bottomRectX);

        //HIDE YOUR NAVIGATION
        $("#" + slideNavName).toggleClass('revealed hidden');
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: For me the codepen is not working correctly. The #slideDown div remains open when scrolling vertically. My intention was for the div to collapse when scrolling vertically, but remain open when scrolling horizontally.

Comment: @AustinBranham sorry, simple typo on variable name...this is resolved now in the above example and demo

Comment: I tried changing that prevLeft variable name before you updated and couldn't get it to work. Maybe one day, or maybe I'll just stick to designing and not developing. Thanks so much for the help!!